# next song on audio playlist not playing

Tags: html, audio

So I was watching a tutorial on how to make a simple music playlist for my website and it all works normal except after the first song is through playing the next song doesn't start up. Which is a problem. Can anyone help me. I'm self taught meaning I'm a beginner the code is below

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var audioArray = document.getElementsByClassName('playsong');
    var nowPlaying = audioArray[0];
    nowPlaying.load();

    $('.play').on('click', function() {
        nowPlaying.play();
    })  

    $('.stop').on('click', function() {
        nowPlaying.pause();

    })  

})

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to reinvent the wheel.

Why don't you try to use the open source plugins like jQuery Audio players

The one i used is mediaelementjs

They have very good tutorials on their home page.

http://mediaelementjs.com/

if you would like more players.

http://www.narga.net/awesome-jquery-audio-video-player-plugins/

or google : jQuery audio players